# Discord.js variable does not exist when defined?

Tags: discord, discord.js, constants, minecraft

I'm trying to code a bot command using discord.js and Minecraft-server-util but my code is not using the const I defined and is saying it does not exist. If you spot any other problems you can correct me on them.

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === `${prefix}javaserverstatus`) {
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' '); // this is where args is defined.
        if (!args.length) {
            return message.channel.send(`You didn't provide a server, ${message.author}!`); // checks if args exist
        }
    if (args.length > 1) {
      return message.channel.send(`Wrong input! EG. play.hypixel.net, ${message.author}`); // checks if there are only 1 arguments
    }

      }
    const util = require('minecraft-server-util');
    var serverinfo = null
    util.status(args) // This code is giving an error saying args does not exist.
     .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        serverinfo = response;
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('play.hypixel.net Server Status')
      .setColor(0xff0000)
      .setDescription('IP: ' + response.host + '\n' + 'Port: ' + response.port + '\n' + 'Version: ' + response.version + '\n' + 'Online Players: ' + response.onlinePlayers.toString() + '\n' + 'Max Players: ' + response.maxPlayers.toString() + '\n');
      message.channel.send(embed);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: What error(s) are you getting and on what variable?

Comment: I'm getting 'args' does not exist on util.status(args) even though its defined at the top below client.on and if message.content

Comment: I've formatted your code which makes it much easier to find errors like issue with scope. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined args in a if statement. You need to put it out of there.

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ') // this is where args is defined.
  if (message.content === `${prefix}javaserverstatus`) {
    if (!args.length) {
      return message.channel.send(`You didn't provide a server, ${message.author}!`) // checks if args exist
    }
    if (args.length > 1) {
      return message.channel.send(`Wrong input! EG. play.hypixel.net, ${message.author}`) // checks if there are only 1 arguments
    }
  }
  const util = require('minecraft-server-util')
  var serverinfo = null
  util
    .status(args) // This code is giving an error saying args does not exist.
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
      serverinfo = response
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('play.hypixel.net Server Status')
        .setColor(0xff0000)
        .setDescription('IP: ' + response.host + '\n' + 'Port: ' + response.port + '\n' + 'Version: ' + response.version + '\n' + 'Online Players: ' + response.onlinePlayers.toString() + '\n' + 'Max Players: ' + response.maxPlayers.toString() + '\n')
      message.channel.send(embed)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error)
    })
})
```

If this isn't working, pls send me the command you sent in the discord chat.

Comment: I can't set 2 answers but you are both correct, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The error is due to the scope that you've defined args in.
args is defined in your first if statement when it should be defined a line above.

```js
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
if (message.content === `${prefix}javaserverstatus`) {
    // this is where args is defined.
    if (!args.length) {
        return message.channel.send(`You didn't provide a server, ${message.author}!`); // checks if args exist
    }
    if (args.length > 1) {
        return message.channel.send(`Wrong input! EG. play.hypixel.net, ${message.author}`); // checks if there are only 1 arguments
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't set 2 answers but you are both correct, thanks.